# How to add CAML query results with ListItems to a datasource of a repeater?

Tags: caml, query

I am using SP2010. I have created a CAML query. This query has listItems as results. I would like to add these items to my repeaters datasource. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
SPListItemCollection items = spList.GetItems(spquery);
repeaterControl.DataSource = items.GetDataTable();
repeaterControl.DataBind();
```